# Google Analytics API reporting value other than real

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I was doing a test here, I do not know if I used the wrong method, I do not think so, but the `ga:timeOnPage` reported by the Google Analytics API is different from the one reported on Google's own panel.

There it shows a mean time of `00:01:35`, while the one reported by the API is `160588.0`. I converted the value obtained from **seconds** (it's in the documentation) to **minutes** and got a result totally out of the reality.

```
...
query({
'ids': 'ga:<?php echo $items[0]->id; ?>',
'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
'metrics': 'ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:timeOnPage',
'start-date': '<?php echo $data_ini; ?>',
'end-date': '<?php echo $data_fim; ?>'
})
...
document.getElementById('total-grafico-3').innerHTML = results[0].totalsForAllResults["ga:timeOnPage"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ga:timeOnPage` - total time on page for chosen period.

You need to use other dimension - `ga:avgTimeOnPage`.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Comment: Truth. I discovered earlier today that the result was not obtained directly by the metric but rather that it should be calculated. But thanks :)